# Forcing autofocus with slideToggle without reloading app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using jQuery slideToggle to toggle an element in my Rails app. When the element is visible I want to autofocus on an input field. `:autofocus => true` works but only for the first time the input field is visible. If I toggle the element back to hide it, then toggle again to show it, the `:autofocus` is gone. I have to refresh the page in order for `:autofocus` to work. Can anyone help me solve this?

Here's my code:

```
<%= link_to 'expand', nil, :class => 'button white', :id => "newForm", :remote => true %></li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('a#newForm').click(function() {
        $('ul.form').slideToggle('500', function() {
            // Animation complete.
            });
    });
});
```

Form:

```
<ul class="form">
  <%= form_for(Object.new) do |f| %>
    <div id="titleHolder">
      <%= f.text_field :title, :id =>"objectProfile", :autofocus => true %>
    </div>
    <div id="placeholder">
      <%= f.text_area :body, :id =>"objectProfile" %>
    </div>
    <li id="button">
      <%= submit_tag 'SUBMIT', :class => 'button orange' %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work for you.

```
$(function(){
    $('a#newForm').click(function() {
        $('ul.form').slideToggle('500', function() {
            $('#titleHolder #objectProfile').focus()
        });
    });
});
```